# Как безопасно увеличить размер раздела Ubuntu

Tags: partition, ubuntu

Есть раздел Ubuntu, рядом с ним прилично свободного места. Какой утилитой или командой можно расширить раздел, никак не повредив при этом файлы и настройки Ubuntu

Answer (score 2, accepted):

gparted,если не изменяет память в Убунте он должен присутствовать сразу с коробки,если нет установите через менеджер пакетов.

Answer (score 1):

Поддерживаю, GParted. Загружаетесь, например, с установочного диска Ubuntu (там он есть по умолчанию) и просто двигаете "границы" раздела. Из-под рабочей системы это сделать не получится.

Если сжимать справа, времени занимает немного, если отрезать куски слева или двигать, будет произведен перенос всей инфы, что процесс весьма небыстрый (прерывать ни в коем случае нельзя, потеря данных гарантированная).

Answer (score 1):

Лучше всего использовать Gparted с LiveDVD, он позаботится об перенесении файлов на начало раздела... А после изменения раздела(его перемещение в другое место) нужно еще позаботиться о его правильном номере UUID в файле "/etc/fstab". Номера UUID разделов диска можно узнать по команде "ls -l /dev/disk/by-uuid"

Answer (score 0):

От акрониса утилиты мегакруты. Делаешь загрузочный диск акронис,затем бэкап Acronis True imageм, затем творишь все что хочешь с файловой системой Акронис Диск директором. Правда придется свежие версии искать - ext совершенcтвуется непрерывно, в отличие от ntfs.

А самые распоследние версии с оффсайта могут быть не поломаны благородными Робин Гудами(

Comment: Круты,только они платные)

Answer (score 0):

Да, Gparted - самое лучшее решение.

Это аналог многих Виндовских программ.

И, конечно же, надо учесть советы выше, особенно о необходимости создания копии Акронисом!